# dynmaic anchor onclick event is not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

i am trying to achieve the same behavior in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CWaHL/1/
but the only difference is my anchor tag  is dynamically generated through jquery

my code

```
   acqIdCounter = grouparr.length;
    $("#attendessbox") .append( "
    <div id='acquiantancebox"+acqIdCounter+"' class='acquaintance'
        style='padding: 1%; float: left; position: relative;'>
        <a href='#' class='deleteAcq' onClick='return false;'>
        <img style='max-width: 100%' src='images/crosserror.png' /></a><span
            style='border: 1px solid #DE4062; width: 100%; border-radius: 4px'>"
            + acquiantancename + "<br />" + acquiantancemob + "
        </span>
    </div>
```

and on click event

```
$('a.deleteAcq').on('click',function(e){
 alert("test");
 return false;
});
```

so issue here, when click on the image 'crosserror.png' my anchor click event is not getting triggered. Thanks for your answers, dont know what i am doing wrong!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event delegation syntax of `on` is different.

```
$(static-eleemnt).on(event, dynamic-element-selector, function(){})
```

Try

```
$(document).on('click','a.deleteAcq',function(e){
    alert("test");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for your reply, just curious , i have my onclick inside document.ready function, what is different from your answer?

Comment: @pappu_kutty you are saying your `a.deleteAcq` elements are created dynamically so when the dom ready function is executed the `deleteAcq` elements may not be present in the dom so the handler will no get attached to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event to the parent, so you catch it when it bubbles up from the dynamically created elements.

```
$('#attendessbox').on('click', 'a.deleteAcq', function(e){
  // Your code
});
```